# Remotely debugging application on a server with no administrator privileges

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

My application runs fine on my machine (Windows laptop) but not on production machine (Windows Server 2012). I don't have administrator rights on production machine, so installing Visual Studio remote tools is not possible. Prod machine does not have Visual Studio installed. What is the best way to debug the application running on remote machine in this case?

To get some idea of what is breaking, I looked at EventViewer on prod machine and I see Exception and got to know which function is causing issue. However, as I am new to C#, I need to be able to set breakpoints and step through the code to understand better and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without remote debugging configured you will not be able tp step trough your code.
Please look at another options like log4Net - when enabled in your application can be very useful to pinpoint a production issue
 (very easy to use and configure) installs from VS package manager